# Как отключить службу cupsd в firefox?

Tags: firefox

Я заметил что при запуске firefox запускаеться служба печати `cupsd` - понятия не имею что это. Но она открывает 631 порт и завершить её можно только `kill -KILL PID`. Она обязательна для функционирования firefox? Или её можно как-то отключить? Если можно то как?

Answer (score 0):

Cups это служба печати для линукс и мак. Фаерфокс опросил список принтеров - служба запустилась.

Comment: А с какой целью он опросил список принтеров, если никто не собирается печатать?

Comment: Например чтоб определиться : нарисовать пункт "печать" в меню или нет